# javascript imports are real-time?

Tags: javascript, import, javascript-import

well, i'm trying to do a snake game using basic imports, but at some time, i got stuck, because of a javascript assignment.

i assigned the value the oldSnake as the value of the snake before its changes.

but as i get into the forEach, the value already assigned changes and i don't know why.

Before getting into the forEach
[image]

After getting into the forEach
[image]

i searched about it, and didn't get anywhere, Does someone know what's happening?

```
import { snake } from "/snake.js";
    let lastDirection = {y: 1, x:0};
    export function updateGame(direction){
        let oldSnake = snake;
        if (!(direction.y == 0 && direction.x == 0)){
            if((lastDirection.y == 1 && direction.y == -1 || lastDirection.y == -1 && direction.y == 1)
            ||(lastDirection.x == 1 && direction.x == -1 || lastDirection.x == -1 && direction.x == 1)){
                direction = lastDirection;
            }
            
            snake.forEach((snakeSlice, index)=>{
                lastDirection = direction;                
                if (index === 0){
                    snakeSlice.ypos+= direction.y;
                    snakeSlice.xpos+= direction.x;
                }
                else{
                    snakeSlice.ypos = oldSnake[index-1].ypos;
                    snakeSlice.xpos = oldSnake[index-1].xpos;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post a minimal but complete code example as formatted text, not images or links.

Comment: referencing an element is just a reference to the object. you are not making a copy.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: ok i just edited.

Comment: Given the `snake.forEach`, `snake` is an array. `let oldSnake = snake;` *does not copy the snake*, it just assigns `oldSnake` to reference the same object.

Comment: ohhh, i got it.